# How to get a count of values in a Pandas DataFrame column within groups?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame with a structure like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'id': ['123', '123', '123', '456', '456', '789'],
        'type': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A']
     })
```

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | A |
| 123 | A |
| 123 | B |
| 456 | B |
| 456 | C |
| 789 | A |

How can I get a count of each type grouped by *id*, and create a new column for each unique type?

The resulting DataFrame I'm looking for would look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'id': ['123', '456', '789'],
        'A': [2, 0, 1],
        'B': [1, 1, 0],
        'C': [0, 1, 0]
    })
```

| id | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 456 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 789 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Thank you for any help and guidance.

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['id'], df['type'])`

Comment: search for "pivot", "unpivot" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
out = df.groupby(['id','type']).size().unstack().fillna(0).astype(int).rename_axis([None])
```

or as @Quang Hoang suggested, simply as

```
out = pd.crosstab(df['id'], df['type']).rename_axis([None])
```

Output:

```
type  A  B  C
123   2  1  0
456   0  1  1
789   1  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function for each column using pd.apply.
For example if you want to count values of column "c" you can do this:

```py
New_column = df["C"].apply(count)
```

New_column is a series of column "c" counts.

Answer (score 0):

Another way by aggregating:

```
df.groupby(['id', 'type']).agg(count=('type', len)).reset_index().pivot(index='id', columns='type', values='count').fillna(0)

type    A   B   C
id          
123 2.0 1.0 0.0
456 0.0 1.0 1.0
789 1.0 0.0 0.0
```